# How to flattern/resize part of a rig but keep curve when already subdivided

Tags: modeling, sculpting

very specific question that i had trouble finding an answer for online.

Basically, I misjudged part of a mesh object I created and I'd like the back of it to be more flat/ small without using the size controls as that only works for axes... hard to explain, so I'll add images.

*This is what the object currently looks like from the top:*
[image: Top view]

*And the red line in this image indicates what i want it to look more like (happy with the Z and Y viewpoints, just the X I'm wanting to edit):*
[image: Top view - what I want]

I tried to sculpt it like that but it won't work with the edges that aren't connected to 2 faces.
Thanks for reading, hope you can help. I know there is probably an obvious solution to this but I am self taught and again couldn't find info online.